# How to use WatchService (NIO Package) & @Scheduled same time in single project of Spring-Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduling, spring-scheduled, watchservice

I have written a script in while I have a schedular class that does something in after every certain time interval and another class in which I am watching a folder continuously for the occurance of any new file. And these both jobs (Schedular + WatchService) has to be endless.

But they are not getting called concurrently.

Called schedular class by - @Scheduled & @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project.schedular")

Calling WatchService by - @PostConstruct on method

Already tried Putting @PostConstruct on both and putting both packages in @ComponentScan({"com.project.schedular","com.project.watcher"})
Also tried putting @Async on both the methods.

Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.aprstc.schedular")

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

```
@Component
public class SchedularClass {

    @PostConstruct
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
    public void execute() {
//logic of scheduling method
}
```

Watcher Class:

```
@Component
public class WaybillReadScript {

@PostConstruct
    public void watchFolder() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Into the watch Folder.");
        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        System.out.println(2);

        Path path = Paths.get("/home/mypc-630/Work/abc");
        System.out.println(3);
        try {

            path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                if (event.context().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("wbill.txt"))
                    processWaybillFile();
            }
            key.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that both classes must run concurrently.
Watcher Must do continuous watching.
And the scheduler must do a continuous scheduled job.

Answer (score 0):

I think the PostConstruct is the wrong place. PostConstruct is used to initialize your beans/components. And if you make a blocking call with watchService.take(), this PostContruct will never be left and if not all beans are completely created than your application with the scheduler will not start.